What does ばらばら here mean?
"道を選んでください"
ばらばらの道を行くのではなく、二人で一つの道を選びたい。
"あなたの直感でかまいません"
The character tells him to another person. the dialogs are all from the same person and tells him to pick a road to continue the chase. But what does ばらばら mean? As far I know it only means "scattered" Instead of going a scattered road?

ばらばら in this context means "all different from one another". ばらばら carries this meaning especially when used as a no-adjective.

ばらばらの道を行くのではなく、二人で一つの道を選びたい。
Rather than going on separate paths, I want to choose one path together with you.

Similar examples:

兄弟はばらばらの場所に住んでいる。
My siblings live in different places.
意見がばらばらで、なかなか結論が出ない。
With everyone having different opinions, we can't reach a conclusion.

